# Retain RSVP reservation to reduce signaling

Tags: rsvp

Does RSVP reservation protocol allow retaining the reserved path by the host for later use? For example, a host A reserves a path for communicating with host B. After communication is complete, can the path be retained for some duration to avoid signaling (related to reservation) if the same host A needs to communicate with host B or any other host in the same network as host B?

Comment: My understanding is that the host refreshes the path periodically by sending path messages. Also RSVP is about reserving resources, it is not tied to a specific TCP session. So as long as you're still refreshing the path you should be fine. If you don't, you can't assume that the original reservation is kept. RSVP also doesn't guarantee that the path stays the same between two refreshes, so that it can adapt to dynamic network changes.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understand that it should be possible for a host A to start subsequent communication with host B without reserving bandwidth again, if it does not tear down the previous session, and continues to send refresh messages. In such a case, if the host A tends to establish communication with another host C, which is in same subnet as host B, can the same path be used?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

RSVP reserves resources along a certain path in the network, but the destination could only be specified by a single address (unicast or multicast) so as far as I know you can neither reserve resources towards a CIDR block, nor send traffic to a different host in the same subnet as the one you initially reserved resources for and assume that the reservation will apply.

The path can be reused so long as you keep refreshing it periodically, and so long as the network doesn't send back an error when you attempt to refresh.